# Place for GitHub Snapshot Archives (Source Code)

Tags: github, version-control, snapshot

I am looking for a place which maintain GitHub archives (Source code) periodically.

My requirement is, I need to analyze status of Java/C++/Python GitHub projects over the past years and identify trends of Softwares. For my analysis, I need the exact picture of GitHub for past couple of years. If there is anyplace which checkout GitHub projects periodically and make it available for research purposes, I would like to know a such place.

NOTE:

- As far as I know GH Archive maintain, history of GitHub events. But what I need is the exact picture of source codes.
- Why I can't go back to the commit history and find the exact picture? I won't be able to consider about deleted project if I consider current picture and try to go back to history.

Comment: Do you want the analytics for all public GitHub repos or for repos from your organization? Each repo contains all the historical code starting from the moment it is created. So you can write a set of scripts that checkout code by date and run analysis.

Comment: @MohanaRao - I want to analyze all the public repos. Yes of course GitHub maintain history of files. But the problem is I want the exact snapshot of GitHub before one year ago.. two year ago..... etc. Even though I can track back for existing projects, what about the deleted projects? That why I want a place which checkout projects for every year and make it available

Comment: in this case, you need to contact GitHub support. They may have these trend reports and share/sell them to you.

Answer (score 0):

For analyzing repos hosted on GitHub.com, you may need to contact GitHub support.

They may have these trend reports and share/sell them to you.

Hope this helps!